# How can I assign latlng coordinate values to JS variables

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Hello I am learning Google Map API from w3schools. I am new to JS and want to assign `location.lat()` and `location.lng()` to JavaScript variables. This is the copied code of tutorials. I am trying to assign the values as;

`var latid=location.lat();` but I think `lat()` is returning nothing.

I have to save coordinates in database. If it is the wrong approach then please tell me what can I do to save `lnglat` coordinates in my database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykeyishidden&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

        function initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center:myCenter,
                zoom:5,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
            });
        }

        function placeMarker(location) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
            });

            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a client-side script. There is no database.

Comment: First of all, please [Avoid Using W3Schools](http://w3fools.com) and spread the word. Main reason is that they have a lot of inaccurate and outdated information. Second, what sort of database are you trying to save to?

Comment: Where are you trying to assign `location.lat()` to a variable

Comment: You should never post your API keys on StackOverflow. Someone will attempt to use them without your permission.

Comment: You may not be allowed to save geolocation data from Google Maps (depending on your use); see the [terms of sersvice](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en#section_10_1_3)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to access location through location.lat() but do not see anything on location on your entire script. I was expecting to see something like

> google.maps.GeocoderGeometry.location

instantiated somewhere.

For your purpose, I think it is better to try the following if it is what you meant:

```
google.maps.LatLng.lat()  // Returns latitude
google.maps.LatLng.lng()  // Returns longitude
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your page and looked into the Console.
In the `placeMarker(location)`, location has these attributes. 
`A: -1.8017578125
k: 49.03786794532644`

Your lat() and lng() are actually returning values, not zero! So, for example, if you needed to store these in use somewhere else in your program, your code would have these things added...

```
<script>
  var map;
  var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
  var myLatLng;
  var myLatLngs[];

  ...

  function placeMarker(location) {
            ...

        myLatLng = {lat:location.lat(),lng:location.lng()};
        console.log("Lat: " + myLatLng.lat + "  Lng: " + myLatLng.lng);
        myLatLngs.push(myLatLng);

        infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
...
```

Now you've got myLatLng which stores the latitude and longitude, myLatLngs which is an array of every time the user clicks and stores these coordinates in order, and a console.log to display it to you to confirm in the console.

If you don't know how to access the browser console by looking at this thread: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers